# Saving serialized ArrayList throws NotSerializableException in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, arraylist

I want to save `ArraList<MyClass>` to internal storage. So, I've implemented Serializable to class which has the ArrayList and also to the MyClass. The code looks like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Serializable { 
public ArrayList<TaskItems> taskList = new ArrayList<TaskItems>();
// some fields and variables
// some methods which use below method saveFile()
public void saveFile() {
    try {
      String filename = "daytodaytasks";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = mContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//mContext is MainActivity context
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(taskList);
        objectOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
class TaskItems implements Serializable {
    String smallRectUpText;
    String smallRectDownText;
    String bigRectText;
    }
}
```

In the class CustomAdapter there are methods which use saveFile() method. All the methods are called from MainActivity onClick() method using class reference. When I run the program and use onClick method by pushing button I get:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.something.MainActivity
```

So I tried to implement Serializable to MainActivity, but then I got the same exception from AppCompatAcitvity, which MainActivity extends. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Context` objects are not `Serializable`.

As class `TaskItems` is not static, it can access `CustomAdapter.this` i.e. `BaseAdapter` object, which contains `Context` Object.

That why when you made `BaseAdapter` serializable, it started showing 
`java.io.NotSerializableException: com.something.MainActivity`

[Java Doc states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the `Serializable` interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object.

Make `TaskItems` a static class, then it will not have access to `CustomAdapter.this` from its static context.

Comment: It works, but I don't get why class TaskItems access CustomAdapter.this. It does not have any reference to the context.

Comment: class TaskItems is inner class, hence it has access to outer class member variables using  CustomAdapter.this, by making class TaskItems static, we prevent the access of member variables of outer class.